# How to save data from multiple selection dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I started learning about the entity framework and asp.net and I wanted to use all CRUD operations.
I have Task and Category models and they are in many-to-many relationship. In my database there are 3 tables: 1.**Task** (it contains Id, Title, Description..), 2.**Category** (it contains categoryId and categoryName) and 3.**TaskCategory** (contains Id (taskId) and categoryId).

I managed to do everything I wanted except to add multiple categories to task using dropdown. I created dropdown, and loaded categories and I know how to add one category to task (when relation is 1:N) (`asp-for="CategoryId"`). For multiple selection I tried with `selectedCategories` (list od integers - ids) instead of CategoryId but I dont know what to do with that list. How to join category and task in TaskCategory while saving task in controller (in other words: how to save categories to task)?

AddTask.cshtml

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Category</label>
    <select class="select-picker" asp-for="selectedCategories"
        asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Categories, "CategoryId", "CategoryName"))" multiple>
    </select>
</div>
```

```html
<script>
    ...
     $('.select-picker').selectpicker('toggle');
</script>
```

HomeController.cs

```
public IActionResult AddTask()
{
    var categories = _categoryRepository.GetAllCategories().OrderBy(c => c.CategoryName);
    var taskCategories = _taskCategoryRepository.GetAllTaskCategories().OrderBy(tc => tc.Id);

    var homeViewModel = new HomeViewModel()
    {
        Task = null,
        TaskCategory = null,
        Categories = categories.ToList(),
        TaskCategories = taskCategories.ToList(),
        selectedCategories = new List<int>()
    };

    return View(homeViewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddTask(Task task, List<int> selected)
{
    // foreach (var selectedCategoryId in selected)
    // {
    //
    // }

    _taskRepository.AddTask(task);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");

    return View();
}
```

This way I get Task in database, but ofcourse without any category saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use ViewModel to handle relationships , the following is the working demo I made , you could refer to and make the modification as per your need

Many-to Many relationship between Task and Category :

```
public class Task
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<TaskCategory> TaskCategories { get; set; }
}
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public List<TaskCategory> TaskCategories { get; set; }
}
public class TaskCategory
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }

    public int TaskId { get; set; }
    public Task Task { get; set; }

}
   //DbContext
    public DbSet<Task> Task { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Category { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TaskCategory> TaskCategory { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<TaskCategory>()
            .HasKey(t => new { t.CategoryId, t.TaskId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<TaskCategory>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.Category)
            .WithMany(p => p.TaskCategories)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.CategoryId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<TaskCategory>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.Task)
            .WithMany(t => t.TaskCategories)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.TaskId);
    }
```

Create a TaskViewModel , a  element posts back an array of its selected option values (which in your case will be an array of the Categories `Id` values). Your model needs a property to bind to. Add the following property:

```
public class TaskViewModel
{ 
    public Task Task { get; set; }
    public SelectList CategoryList { get; set; }
    public List<int> selectedCategories { get; set; }
}
```

AddTask.cshtml:

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.Tasks.TaskViewModel
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <form asp-action="AddTask">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Task.Title" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Task.Title" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Task.Title" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="selectedCategories" class="control-label"></label>
            <select asp-for="selectedCategories" class="form-control" asp-items="Model.CategoryList" multiple></select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then in Post method , the value of `selectedCategories` will contain an array of `CategoryId` values that you selected in the view.

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult AddTask(TaskViewModel taskVM)
    {
        Models.Tasks.Task task = taskVM.Task;
        _context.Add(task);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        foreach(var selectedId in taskVM.selectedCategories)
        {
            _context.TaskCategory.Add(new TaskCategory
            {
                TaskId = task.Id,
                CategoryId = selectedId,
            });
        }
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was missing this middle part in post method and didn't know how to add new row in Taskcategory while adding new Task so I combined your code with mine and it works perfectly now

Comment: @Xueli Chen Why in my case there is no any options in select?